# ビデオカメラの配信（ストリーミング）のキャプチャーについて

Tags: android, java

こんにちは。

ビデオカメラからのWiFi配信を受信するコードについての相談です。

パナソニックのHC-V550Mというビデオカメラを持っています。

WiFiストリーミング機能が付いていて、Androidで専用アップのImageAppを使えば
問題なくリアルタイムで撮った映像が画面に映っています。

ただ、そのストリーミングのビデオデータを別のプログラムに必要としているので、
自分でプログラムを書いてJAVAのUIでメーカのプログラムと同じように
ストリーミングをデコードし映像を表示したいのです。

現時点では、カメラとの接続ができています。
JAVAプログラムを作りUDPポートも作っています。

UbuntuのターミナルではUDPポートからストリーミングができることを確認しています。
しかし、Liveviewを使う場合ストリーミングが流れていません。
JAVAのUIで何でできない理由を知りたいので、指導できる方がいれば嬉しいです。

Comment: teratailにも質問されているのですね。複数サイトで質問すると両サイトに回答や参考情報が分散してしまいますから、せめてそのことを書いていただけると有難いです。 https://teratail.com/questions/12978

Comment: 「こうすれば自作アプリで受信できます」という資料がメーカーから提示されているのですか？あるいは「純正アプリを真似すれば自作アプリでもできるだろう」ということでしょうか。

Comment: メーカはそういう面では協力する方針ではないので、こちらでゼロから作ることになります。　別にメーカのアプリを真似しなくても結構ですが、できるはずのことができないのでアドバイスを求めています。

Comment: 何を根拠に「できるはず」と仰っているのかが分かりません。少なくともメーカのアプリの真似をしない限り無理だと思うんですが、UDPポートを作っただけなのですか？